# Ruby on Rails jQuery Visual Effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jrails

I am working on a search function on RoR that basically just has a cool visual effect when a user clicks the search button.

Here is the code in my view for search.rhtml

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Tutor</title>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1></h1>
        <%= form_remote_tag :url =>{ :action => :search_results }, :update => "results"  %>


                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Tutor Search.</legend>
                        <label for="searchItField">Keyword Search.</label>

                        <input class="tfield" type="text" value="FIND YOUR TUTOR HERE" name="searchItField" id="searchItField" />
                        <span id="Submit_search">

                            <span id="Submit_search_hover"><input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Search" /></span>

                        </span>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>

    <div id="results">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the search_results.rhtml which is what gets displayed in the results div in search.rhtml

```
<% for tutors in @tutors %>
        <%= tutors.first_name %> <br/>
    <% end %>
```

And finally here is my controller and actions.

```
class TutorsController < ApplicationController

  def search
  end

  def search_results
     @tutors = Tutors.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM tutors')
  end

end
```

What I want to do is basically create an effect that when the search results are loaded because of the ajax call that it would slide up. I am using jrails. Exactly how this site does it. http://keyonary.com/#/paste

Comment: So, what is your problem? Is it that you don't understand the Keyonary.com code?

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to replicate that jquery effect on the search results. Does anybody have any insights on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, to get you started, you will need to do the following:

- use `observe_field` on the input-field, which retrieves data from a controller-method and will update a certain div with the results
- create a corresponding controller-method that will retrieve the items (use your `search_results`)
- create a view for that controller-method that will show the data with the required effects and animation.

Comment: How would I make an effect on the results returned?

Comment: I suggest you look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Animate_me:_Using_Effects to get you started ...